# Bootstrap's Javascript Varying modal content based on trigger button

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

I am using this Javascript 
[Varying modal content based on trigger button](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target)

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@mdo">Open modal for @mdo</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@fat">Open modal for @fat</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@getbootstrap">Open modal for @getbootstrap</button>
...more buttons...

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Recipient:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Message:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

```
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
    var recipient = button.data('whatever'); // Extract info from data-* attributes
    // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
    // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
    var modal = $(this);
    modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient);
    modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient);
});
```

If I click on Send Message, nothing happens.

How do I enable Submit?

Comment: Add linked code

Comment: JS code formatted

Answer (score 0):

Change line of button for

```
<button id="buttonSend" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
```

Change  tag form Line

```
<form id="frm">
```

Define event for button

```
$(document).on("click", "#buttonSend", function (event) {
    // Your ID Form
    $("#frm").submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to put your `<form>` after the `<div class="modal-content">` having all the form elements, including buttons, inside it like this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form>
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Recipient:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Message:</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Working in Chrome Version 95.0.4638.54 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Using Bootstrap's default starter html template and Bootstrap varying modal data example. Functions as intended as of 11/3/2021.

All dependencies for Jquery, Popper, and Bootstrap JS are retrieved through jsdelivr.

**Sources:**

Bootstrap 4 Modal Documentation
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Bootstrap 4 Starter HTML Template
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

**Tip for bootstrap developers:** Ensure you look at the link to bootstrap documentation to see which version you are reviewing before adopting code changes.
(docs/4.0 vs docs/5.0, etc.)

Source Code Full:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap 4.2.1 CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@mdo">Open modal for @mdo</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@fat">Open modal for @fat</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@getbootstrap">Open modal for @getbootstrap</button>

    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Recipient:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Message:</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <!--JQuery 3.6.0-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap 4.2.1 Bundle with Popper 2.9.2 -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
            var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
            var recipient = button.data('whatever');
            var modal = $(this);
            modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient);
            modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient);
        });
    });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```