# webpage passing value (from console) to edit button to edit

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, button

this is the demo I study [demo link01](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/modal/#varying-modal-content)and [demo link02](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40712766/bootstraps-javascript-varying-modal-content-based-on-trigger-button) in order to get the edit button

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap 4.2.1 CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@mdo">Open modal for @mdo</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@fat">Open modal for @fat</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@getbootstrap">Open modal for @getbootstrap</button>

    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Recipient:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Message:</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <!--JQuery 3.6.0-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap 4.2.1 Bundle with Popper 2.9.2 -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
            var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
            var recipient = button.data('whatever');
            var modal = $(this);
            modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient);
            modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient);
        });
    });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

---

I tried to write a new function that can edit the old data(extract from api, data type is object ) but it not success yet.

```
    $(function(){
        $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event ,data) {
            console.log("EDIT DATA", data)
            var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
            var recipient = button.data('whatever');
            var device_id = data.device_id
            var modal = $(this);
            modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient);
            modal.find('.modal-deviceid input').val(data.device_id);  
        });
    });
```

I done:

1. when click edit, can catch that row's data, datatype is object [(pic) can catch data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwulU.png)
2. as demo, can pop up " data-whatever" as default/old data to edit[(pic2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ot02S.png)

**Q: So, how can I make these two concept into 1?**
**Passing my "geted data" from console, to edit button to edit**

I'm a freshman, I really need a hand to overcome the problem, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I study that using following code I correct, could be work

```
      var rowData; 

      $('#example tbody').on('click', 'button', function (event) {  


        var data = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
        rowData = data;

        console.log("GET edit DATA", data)        

      });
```

````
      $(function(){
        $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

          var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
          var recipient = button.data('whatever');
         
          var data = rowData;
          
          // getEditData
          var modal = $(this);
          modal.find('.modal-title').text('Update data ' + recipient);
          var inputFields = modal.find('.modal-body input');
          var keys = Object.keys(data);
          for (var i = 0; i < inputFields.length; i++) {
            var inputValue = data[keys[i]];
            $(inputFields[i]).val(inputValue);
          }
        });
      });
  

```
````

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).